# Copy table from Dev DB to QA DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to copy a table from dev database to QA database in SQL Server using the Import/Export Wizard. There are about 6.6 million rows and it is taking around 7 hours to do it. Is there any faster way to accomplish the task?

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    [Table_Name] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE   [ColumnDate] > 2018  
OR      [Code] in ('A', 'B', 'C','D')
```

Thanks.

Comment: import/export wizard writes records to a file right? did you try copying records with `insert into select` command by linking servers? have a look at here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6009/how-to-copy-a-table-in-sql-server-to-another-database/

Comment: At the risk of sounding pedantic, this is not a table copy,  It's a copy of query results which is quite different than a straight table copy.  Does the query run well if you just run it by itself in a query window?  If it takes 7 hours to run by itself then making the copy to the other instance faster is not where you need to focus your efforts immediately - you need to tune the query.  Without knowing anything else, indexes on `ColumnDate` and `Code` come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the script of the table with data and then use that to create table in your destination database. It is one of the fastest approach. You can also use powershell script to automate it. Since your data is too large and SSMS is slow you are facing the issue of time.

Let me explain when you try to use import/ export property it basically takes more time because it will try to create schema and then insert data one by one. It will be like creating a table and performing insert of each row sequentially.
To avoid this situation you can simply generate script of table with data. Once you get the script you can perform insert into. Since you performing bulk insert from local it will avoid sequential insert and will reduce insert time exponentially.
For reference you can go through the link for step by step guide.

https://www.sqlshack.com/six-different-methods-to-copy-tables-between-databases-in-sql-server/

Comment: Link only answer is useless. Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: I have updated it.